# ionic +sqlite working in browser but TypeError on real device

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I am still working on my first ionic app, and again I am stuck with a problem:

My app uses SQLite to store data. I use the sqlite-plugin from ngCordova and the cordova-sqlite-storage plugin from litehelpers.

If I test the app with 'ionic serve --lab' everything works fine. No errors, the database is there, the data is ok...

But if I go and test it on an Android device 'ionic run android -l -c -s' I get the following error, and the application freezes:

```
0     779681   error    TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined
    at Object.execute (http://192.168.1.14:8100/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js:6872:11)
    at new <anonymous> (http://192.168.1.14:8100/js/controllers.js:284:18)
    at Object.instantiate (http://192.168.1.14:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18010:14)
    at $controller (http://192.168.1.14:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23412:28)
    at self.appendViewElement (http://192.168.1.14:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:59900:24)
    at Object.switcher.render (http://192.168.1.14:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57893:41)
    at Object.switcher.init (http://192.168.1.14:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57813:20)
    at self.render (http://192.168.1.14:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:59759:14)
    at self.register (http://192.168.1.14:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:59717:10)
    at updateView (http://192.168.1.14:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:65398:23)
```

My app has 4 pages, and works with the ui-router. Every page has it's own controller.

I am searching and trying since two weeks, but no chance...

Any hints?

Thanks,
Christian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: loading the database on the device takes longer, and out of the box Ionic (-> AngularJS -> JavaScript) doesn't wait for task.

So I had to use promises:

- http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Now It works...